Can you prove that the logarithm is concave using the fact that $x>0$ implies $\log(x) \leq x - 1$?
I am trying to prove that the natural logarithm is concave by using the fact that for $x>0, \log(x) \leq x - 1$. But I’m not sure if this is possible now. So far I have done the following:
Suppose $a = (1-\lambda) u + \lambda v$, where $u$ and $v$ are positive and $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
Then I want to show
$$\log(a) \geq \lambda \log(v) + (1-\lambda)\log(u).$$
Using the above, we have
$$\log(a) \leq a - 1,$$
$$\log(v) \leq v - 1,\text{ and }\log(u) \leq u - 1.$$
So,
$$\lambda \log(v) + (1-\lambda)\log(u) \leq \lambda (v-1) + (1-\lambda)(u-1) = a - 1.$$
But I don’t know how to go from here. Can you direct me to the right direction?
Thank you!

Just that fact alone is not sufficient. Surely you can think of functions that satisfy $f(x) \leq x-1$, but otherwise look very crazy? They might not even be continuous!

@CalvinLin do you think I should use AM-GM to do this then?

My understanding, which could be mistaken, is that you determine whether a function is concave or convex by studying the behavior of its second derivative.  Similar to the idea in the comment of Calvin Lin, you are apparently not given any information about the second derivative of the function.

@user2661923 I want to try proving it using the definition rather than calculus

Good point, but you are missing a nuance from my comment.  That is, while you don't wish to use the second derivative, there is no denying that the behavior of the second derivative is unconstrained,  based on your posted question.  Therefore, the issue of whether the function is concave can not be solvable.

This is equivalent to $x\leq   e^{x-1}$ which follows if you know Bernoulli's inequality and $(1+y/n)^n\to e^y.$

You can also use the power series to compute $e^{x-1}$ to get,$$1+(x-1)+\sum_{n\geq2} (x-1)^n/n!$$ with the sum obviously greater than  or equal to $0$ when $x\geq1.$ When $0<x<1,$ the sum is a decreasing alternating series, so also sums to a positive value.

If  instead you define $\log x=\int_1^x\frac{dt}t,$ you,easily get if for $x\geq 1$ since $\frac1{t}\leq 1$ for $t\geq 1,$ so $\log(x)\leq\int_1^x,dt=x-1.$ Then you are left with the $0<x<1$ case.

When $0<x<1,$ $$-\ln (x)=\ln(1/x)=\int_1^{1/x}\frac{dt}t\geq\int_1^{1/x}\frac{dt}{1/x}=\frac{1/x-1}{1/x}=1-x.$$

In sum, it all depends on how you define things, and what you know already.

If $f:(0, \infty) \to\mathbb{R} $ is a function such that $f(x) \leq x-1$ and $f(xy) =f(x) +f(y) $ for all positive real numbers $x, y$ then $f(x) =\log x$ and we can derive any of its properties starting with these two conditions.

As a starting point you should first establish that $f'(x) =1/x$. This is possible by using the inequality mentioned in last comment and its counterpart obtained by replacing $x$ with $1/x$.

As noted in the comments, it is not made clear what else you already know and can use about $\log$. Here is an elementary argument that works for any function $\log\colon\mathbb R_{>0}\to\mathbb R$ such that
$$\begin{align}
\tag1\log x&\le x-1,\\
\tag2\log(xy)&=\log x+\log y,\\
\tag3\log x^\lambda&=\lambda\log x,\\
\tag4x<y&\implies\log x<\log y
\end{align}$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. Actually, only (1) and (2) are needed: these imply (4) as
$$x<y\implies\log(xy^{-1})\le xy^{-1}-1<0\implies
\log x=\log(xy^{-1})+\log y<\log y,$$
and it is also easy to show that (2) and (4) imply (3) (proof sketch: using (2), prove (4) successively for $\lambda=0$, $\lambda=-1$, $\lambda\in\mathbb Z$, $\lambda\in\mathbb Q$, and finally, using (4), for $\lambda\in\mathbb R$).
Let $u,v,\lambda,a$ be as in the question. Puting $w=u^{1-\lambda}v^\lambda$, we have
$$v-w=w\bigl((vu^{-1})^{1-\lambda}-1\bigr)\ge w\log\bigl((vu^{-1})^{1-\lambda}\bigr)=w(1-\lambda)\log(vu^{-1})$$
using (1) and (3), thus
$$v\ge\bigl(1+(1-\lambda)\log(vu^{-1})\bigr)w,$$
and a similar calculation yields
$$u\ge\bigl(1-\lambda\log(vu^{-1})\bigr)w.$$
Summing these together, we get
$$a\ge\bigl[(1-\lambda)\bigl(1-\lambda\log(vu^{-1})\bigr)+\lambda\bigl(1+(1-\lambda)\log(vu^{-1})\bigr)\bigr]w=w,$$
which implies
$$\log a\ge\log w=(1-\lambda)\log u+\lambda\log v$$
using (4), (2), and (3).

We could start with a simple lemma: $\forall x, y\in\mathbb R_+^*, x<y\implies{\tag 1 \log\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)>\frac{\log(x)+\log(y)}2}$
Let us use $a=\sqrt{\log(x)}$ and $b=\sqrt{\log(y)}$, the inequation $(1)$ can be written as $ab<\frac{a^2+b^2}2$, or $a^2 -2ab+b^2 >0$. This way is evident because if $x\ne y$, $a\ne b$ hence $(a-b)^2>0$
As any point $z$ inside the interval $]x, y[$ (say $y = \alpha x + (1-\alpha)y$ with $\alpha \in]0;1[$) can be approximated at an arbitrary precision by dichotomy, and as the $\log$ function is continuous, we can conclude that $\log(z)>\alpha\log(x)+(1-\alpha)\log(y)$, proving that the function is concave.
